# threejs linewidth property with LineSegmentsGeometry and LineSegments2

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to make lines that are wider than one pixel using the `LineMaterial` and `LineSegments2` classes that are included with the threejs examples.

I'm trying to follow the pattern given in the answer to this question: [Three.js r91 - how do I use the new linewidth property to fatten/widen lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49368180/three-js-r91-how-do-i-use-the-new-linewidth-property-to-fatten-widen-lines)

However, I can't get the line segments to show up as line segments.

If my code looks like this:

```
const sourcePoint = new THREE.Vector3(ctx.x * window.sceneSettings.size_adjustment,
                                      ctx.y * window.sceneSettings.size_adjustment,
                                      ctx.z * window.sceneSettings.size_adjustment)
const line_geom = new THREE.Geometry()
window.meshObjects.map(sphere => {
  if (sphere.userData.strain == targetStrain && sphere.userData.group != "Nationwide") {
    const targetPoint = sphere.position
    line_geom.vertices.push(sourcePoint, targetPoint)
  }
})
const edges = new THREE.WireframeGeometry(line_geom)
var lsgeom = new THREE.LineSegmentsGeometry().setPositions(edges.attributes.position.array)
const lineMaterial = new THREE.LineMaterial({ color: 0x000000, linewidth: 10 })
lineMaterial.resolution.set( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
var lines = new THREE.LineSegments2(lsgeom, lineMaterial)
lines.computeLineDistances()
scene.add(lines)
```

The lines don't show up at all.

If I do this instead (which seems the most correct):

```
const edges = new THREE.LineSegments(line_geom)
var lsgeom = new THREE.LineSegmentsGeometry().fromLineSegements(edges)
const lineMaterial = new THREE.LineMaterial({ color: 0x000000, linewidth: 10 })
lineMaterial.resolution.set( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
var lines = new THREE.LineSegments2(lsgeom, lineMaterial)
```

I get this error:  `THREE.LineSegmentsGeometry.computeBoundingSphere(): Computed radius is NaN. The instanced position data is likely to have NaN values`

If I try using an `EdgeGeometry` as the intermediate element, I get a box at 0, 0, 0, rather than the line segments I'm trying to create. I've tried a bunch of other alternatives, such as converting the geometry to a `BufferGeometry` and then calling `setPositions` on `LineSegmentsGeometry`, but that just gives me the error on `computeBoundingSphere` again.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you checked the line_geom vertices to have valid values in there? Had a similar issue with BufferAttributes where the array was not correctly initialized.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to draw a 3-line segment in between these three coordinates:

```js
const coordinates = [
    0, 0, 0,   // First segment coordinate
    1, 0, 0,   // Second segment coordinate
    1, 1, 0,   // Third segment coordinate
  ];
```

You should call `setPositions` with this value:

```js
const positions = [
    0, 0, 0,   // First segment: Start point
    1, 0, 0,   // First segment: End point

    1, 0, 0,   // Second segment: Start point
    1, 1, 0,   // Second segment: End point

    1, 1, 0,   // Third segment: Start point
    0, 1, 0    // Third segment: End point
  ];
```

Probably your `edges.attributes.position.array` contain values like the ones in the `coordinates` variable in my first code sample, or an array of `Vector3`s.